# IWorkspaceEdit2Proxy equivalent in ArcGis Javascript api

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there any equivalent for IWorkspaceEdit2Proxy in JS ArcGis API ? I've gone through the whole JS API documentation and haven't seen anything that would help to implement grouping edit operations.

I need to implement the same behaviour in Web application that is used in Desktop app. In ArcObjects SDK I can easily group edits and discard all of them later simple by using methods like IWorkspaceEdit2Proxy.stopEditing() IWorkspaceEdit.startEditing() and so on. However, it seems to me that ArcGIS Server manages edits applied on versioned dataset in his own way.

What can I do?

Comment: Please give a link what you mean by IWorkspaceEdit2Proxy. I don't see it since version 9.3.

Comment: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geodatabase/IWorkspaceEdit2Proxy.html